# laradock refer to workspace directory path

Tags: docker, laradock, princexml

I have successfully installed Prince via the docker-compose.yml and I see the path + executable I need inside my workspace container but calling it out a number of ways in my Laravel .env will not find that path. In order to use prince I need to tell it where the PRINCE_EXECUTABLE_PATH is via the .env.  What is the correct way to hit a directory in the workspace container from the Laravel app? I have tried to set a variable in the Laradock env and refer to it from laradock_workspace_1 and also just put the actual path in the env -- nothing seems to find it. What is the correct way?

Comment: You can’t install software in a `docker-compose.yml` file; usually you’d use a `Dockerfile` to build a custom image, and either install things into “the normal system path” (isolated in the container’s filesystem space) or a known fixed directory name.  Do you have a [mcve], including the actual files involved, that you can include in the question?

Comment: I have used a dockerfile and I see the installed data when i ssh into the container. What I'm having issues with is having Laravel "see" this path in the .env